# What if I assign every user group to a Super User?

Tags: acl, user-groups, joomla-3.9, super-user

This idea came to me when I was trying to formulate a question on this site found [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/28432/14452).

Ok, bear with me, before you scream at me not to make every single user a super user, let me explain. This is in need of disambiguation.

**What could be the disadvantages and detrimental effects of setting 2?**

This is the setting now, setting 1, very regular, nothing special:

```
Name   Username  Enabled  Activated  User Groups
----   ----      ----     ----       ----
one    one       yes      yes        Administrator
two    two       yes      yes        custom1
three  three     yes      yes        custom2
derp   derp      yes      yes        Super Users
```

What if I changed it to this, setting 2?:

```
Name   Username  Enabled  Activated  User Groups
----   ----      ----     ----       ----
one    one       yes      yes        Administrator
two    two       yes      yes        custom1
three  three     yes      yes        custom2
derp   derp      yes      yes        Super Users, Administrator, custom1, custom2
```

To be very clear, this, setting 3, would be suicide and I **don't** mean to do this. I am aware that's not any better than doing something like `sudo rm / -rf` on a linux machine (**for the record, don't do this!**).

```
Name   Username  Enabled  Activated  User Groups
----   ----      ----     ----       ----
one    one       yes      yes        Administrator, Super Users
two    two       yes      yes        custom1, Super Users
three  three     yes      yes        custom2, Super Users
derp   derp      yes      yes        Super Users
```

Setting 2 would be a solution to my predicament in [my recent other question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/28432/14452) (same link as above).

Comment: Your setting 2 looks fine to me. By the way, the best tutorial information I've come across regarding Joomla ACL and Access is at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial and the video at https://youtu.be/CFqXAc3orkY (between 2 mins and 32 mins is the section to watch).

Comment: To be able to answer what the advantages/disadvantages of a particular structure we would need to know a lot more about your requirements. By default Joomla provides the ACL in Hierarchical format which is the same as the document linked by @RobbieJackson . I would suggest you also look at a Roles Based ACL structure which if nothing else will help you understand the Joomla ACL better. I prefer roles based for sites needing anything more than the basics. This is Joomla specific as a start, https://magazine.joomla.org/all-issues/september-2012/implementing-role-based-acl

Answer (score 1):

In fact, Setting 2 would only make sense to me if you..

...Have no inheritance of permissions to the top

...Only one usergroup has access to a specific task

Then it makes sense, if the superuser should simply have all tasks / views  / options of the custom 1/2 groups this can be solved by inheritance in a cleaner way.

Edit: indeed superuser has no inherited permissions my idea was to create a custom „superuser“ aka build a structure with groups and privileges inherited as you need it.

I think you already know this page but for other readers, here the ACL structure is explained:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. ~~Super User~~ derp does not inherit viewing access from custom groups automatically. I have to make derp a member of custom groups to view custom group content on the front end. You say there's a cleaner way to solve this by inheritance. I am very interested in that solution, if I may ask you to add it to your answer.

Comment: see my edit - sorry i‘ve not noted everything clearly... an own group structure would be the way i would go...